# How to run 2 forms without a messagebox on form 1 freezing form 2

Tags: c#, .net, forms

On my first form I have a button that starts a second form. The second form start a RDP. everyting works fine but when I get a messagebox-message on form 1, I can't acces my second form untill I close the messagebox. How can I run the 2 forms apart from each other?

Comment: MessageBoxes are intended to be modal, by their very nature. If you mean your RDP does not run until you close the messagebox then you need to look into using a thread for this

Comment: Can't be done unless you roll your own messagebox. Messageboxes are modal to the application.

Comment: the RDP runs fine. The problem is that when i get (after some time) a messagebox on form 1, both forms freezes. I want that form 1 freeze but I should be able to use form 2 and the messagebox on form 1 at the same time

Comment: Is it WPF or WinForm?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a non modal (modeless) message to the user, you should create a form and use its **Show** method, instead of showing a message box. The following simple method creates and shows a form that looks like a message box:

```
public static Form ShowNonModalMessageBox(string title, string text)
{
    Form form = new Form();
    form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    form.MinimizeBox = false;
    form.MaximizeBox = false;
    form.Size = new Size(200, 100);
    form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    form.Text = title;

    form.SuspendLayout();

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = text;
    label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    form.Controls.Add(label);

    Button okButton = new Button();
    okButton.Text = "OK";
    okButton.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
    okButton.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        form.Close();
    };
    form.Controls.Add(okButton);

    form.ResumeLayout();

    form.Show();
    return form;
}
```

You can then use this method like this to show a non-modal message to the user:

```
Form messageBox = ShowNonModalMessageBox("Title", "This is the message.");
messageBox.FormClosed += messageBox_FormClosed;

private void messageBox_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form closed with result: " + ((Form)sender).DialogResult.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but 1) Form 1 still needs to freeze and 2) The (heavily modified) messageboxes are from an other developper and I can't change them

Answer (score 0):

You should start the forms with the `Show()` method instead of `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: I use the Show()-method. When the second form is shown I can acces it but my users need to switch between the two forms. When doing some new actions on form 1 they can get a messagebox, and then they can't open the second form untill closing the messagebox

Comment: You could try to open the second form in a separate process all together?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`, which displays your form as modal Dialog.

Comment: I use the Show()-method. When the second form is shown I can acces it but my users need to switch between the two forms. When doing some new actions on form 1 they can get a messagebox, and then they can't open the second form untill closing the messagebox

Answer (score 0):

You can call the native MessageBox:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int MessageBoxW(IntPtr hWnd, String lpText, String lpCaption, uint uType);
```

The first parameter is the parent handle, if you pass IntPtr.Zero the MessageBox will be parent-less.
Made available an example https://github.com/mgigirey/MessageBoxWrapper/tree/master.